# Facebook test reading user_birthday property off user profile

Tags: facebook, sitecore

I have a website (using Sitecore) which enables login with Facebook. I want to configure the corresponding Facebook App to allow reading the user_birthday property from a user's Facebook profile. As far as I can tell, the app needs to be reviewed before I can do this, but in order to be reviewed the app needs to have a public-facing privacy policy page - my site is running locally so the privacy policy page is inaccessible to Facebook for the approval process. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: If your app is not publicly accessible, then you should tell them that in your review instructions, and provide an extensive screencast that shows your app in action.

Comment: I can't even submit it for review without the privacy policy URL though :-( Perhaps it would be ok if the privacy policy page was not on the same domain as the test site?

Comment: Yes, of course, that is perfectly fine - your policy can be placed anywhere you like, it just needs to be accessible to Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for an app to be reviewed it does need to have a privacy policy page. However, it does not necessarily have to be on the same domain as the site. My app is for a development version of the site (running on my machine) so I set the *Privacy Policy URL* to the URL of the production site's privacy policy page. This enables me to submit the site for review.